# Backend extension not working with other libraries

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

in my custom extension for typo3 which is ported from 6.2.9 to 7.6.9 I want to use jquery and bootstrap.js

But if I use both one of them is not working well.

in my layoutfile I define this:

```
<f:be.container>

    <script src="{f:uri.resource(path:'js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="{f:uri.resource(path:'js/bootstrap.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{f:uri.resource(path:'js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Chart JS -->
    <script src="{f:uri.resource(path:'js/Chart.min.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="{f:uri.resource(path:'css/resultrepository.css')}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="{f:uri.resource(path:'css/bootstrap.min.css')}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Globales JavaScript für das Result Repository Modul -->
    <script src="{f:uri.resource(path:'js/rereGlobal.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- JS for Noteverwaltung.html -->
    <script src="{f:uri.resource(path:'js/noteverwaltung.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- FontAwesome -->
    <link href="{f:uri.resource(path:'css/font-awesome.min.css')}" rel="stylesheet">
```

In this case what could be the problem? Former when I used it in typo3 6.2.9 it worked fine with the code above. Just in 7.6.9 only jquery or bootstrap.js is working.

Comment: Could you confirm your TYPO3 version? Is it 7.4.9 or 7.6.9?

Comment: Its TYPO3 7.6.9 LTS

Comment: do you have any Idea what the problem could be

Comment: Do you get errors in the console? Can you further specify how the libraries are "not working well"? I assume there is a conflict of different versions of jQuery being used at the same time?

Comment: No errors. When I comment out jquery in Extension Template Bootstrap.js (nav Dropdown and tooltips) work fine. But no jquery function of my own js is working. It says $ is no function. When I comment out Bootstrap.js Dropdown an Tooltip is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the jQuery is included twice, if your Dropdown and tooltips work without you including jQuery. Check the source code for jQuery and figure out where it is being included and which version is needed for your code to run properly.

Comment: Yes thats right. Jquery is loaded twice. One time from typo3 and one time from my Extension Layout. But if I delete it from Extension Layout in Console I got the error that $() is not a function ... why?

Comment: In typo3 6.2.9 it worked fine. Its the same jquery Version

Comment: @Felix Probably TYPO3 uses jQuery in compatibility mode (not sure), so jQuery does not define the function `$()`, but only `jQuery()`.

Comment: Which is the same version? Did you have 2 jQuery versions included for 6.2.9 as well? Were they included in the same order?

Answer (score 1):

`<f:be container>` doesn't load Jquery by default.But You can add the `loadJQuery` property to it. Then remove the markup for including jquery.Then clear the cache.Hopes it works.

```
<f:be.container  loadJQuery="true"></f:be.container>
```